# Discrete Mathematics Groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of the identity element $1$ and $a, b, c \in G$.

Show that $bac=a^{-1}$ implies $cab = $a^{-1}$

I know that $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = 1$, should i do something like this $cabc^{-1}b^{-1}$??

but after that i get stuck somebody has some hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $(cab)a = (cab)acc^{-1} = ca(bac)c^{-1}$